# How do you animate multiple elements with the same class name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

Why does the following function only work on 1 class and not 3 of them?

```
function animateLetter( w, t, z ){
    for( i=0; i<3; i++){            
         $(document.getElementsByClassName(w)).find('spanny').eq(z).animate({fontSize:"40px"}, {duration:t}).text();        
    }
}
animateLetter( 'word', 1000, 2 );
```

Here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/AuLah/1/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is in `.eq(z)`; You are finding all `spanny` elements that are descendents of all `.word` divs, then taking only index `2` of that collection.

I assume you want to do [this](http://jsfiddle.net/R8kcu/1/) instead:

```
$('.' + w)
    .find('spanny:nth-child(' + (z + 1) + ')')
    .animate({fontSize:"40px"}, {duration:t})
    .text();
```

...or combine your selector even further and remove that `text()` which does nothing:

```
$('.' + w + ' spanny:nth-child(' + (z + 1) + ')').animate({fontSize:"40px"}, {duration:t});
```